# Java Reflection getDeclaredMethod() with Generic Class Type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a method in class A:

```
class Parameter {
...
}

class A {
   private <T extends B> void call(T object, Parameter... parameters){
   ...
   }
}
```

Now I want to use reflection to get the method "call",

```
A a = new A();
// My question is what should be arguments in getDeclaredMethod
//Method method = a.getClass().getDeclaredMethod()
```

Thx.

Comment: `Class a = new A();` is not valid. You either mean `Class a = new A().getClass();` or `A a = new A();`.

Comment: sorry, I mean A a = new A().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They should be `B` and `Parameter[]`, since `B` is the [erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) of `T` and varargs are implemented as arrays:

```
Method method = a.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
        "call",
        B.class,
        Parameter[].class
);
```

Note that you have a syntax error: `<T extends of B>` should be `<T extends B>`.

Also note that the method as you're showing it doesn't need to be generic at all. This would work just as well:

```
private void call(B object, Parameter... parameters) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, It works! I also have updated the syntax error. Btw, I wonder why B.class works here and what Parameter[].class means.

Comment: @user537555 Glad to help! `.class` returns the `Class` literal representing that type. It works for array types like `Parameter[].class` and even primitive types like `int.class` (that's how you can look up a method taking an `int`).